# Formatting fields to add dashes in SSRS

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am pulling a string of numbers from a database and am wanting to format them with dashes between them. More specifically, I want them to go from looking like 
this: 

1234567890 

to this:

12345-67-890

I've tried to change the format through Placeholder Properties, but it's not working. I think it might be because it is a string.

My code looks like this:

```
Format(Fields!NUM.Value, "#####-##-###")
```

and I get #####-##-### returned when I run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an expression to apply this formatting to the numbers. You can either use this expression directly in the report or add it as a calculated field to the dataset if it will be referenced in multiple places.

```
=Left(Fields!NUM.Value, 5) + "-" + Mid(Fields!NUM.Value, 6, 2) + "-" + Right(Fields!NUM.Value, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've actually used that expression before, but with `Parameters!`. Kinda feel dumb not that I didn't think to try it for `Fields!`.

Comment: This is a very workable solution. Another solution would be to specifically cast the values as numbers using [CInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). EG: `Format(CInt(Fields!NUM.Value), "#####-##-###")`. Mostly posting this in case someone comes along with variable length numeric strings for which `left,mid,right` will not work.